# How to store data from if statement inside a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

In the for loop, you only can keep the last result from the for loop.  I want to save the data each time I finish from the for loop. I can't put the index of the for loop because not all variables are satisfying the if statement: my code is:

```
c=[1 3 2 3 3];p=[0 0 1 2 1];level2=[1 3];
for j=1:length(level2)
    for i=1:length(p)
        a=[p(i),c(i)]';
        if a(1,:)==level2(j)
            level3=a(2)
        else
        end
    end
end
```

So, how can I make `level3` as a vector for all results from the for loop?  Note that `p`,`c` and `level2` should be dynamic values, but here they are static to make the example much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following

```
c=[1 3 2 3 3];p=[0 0 1 2 1];level2=[1 3];
level3=[];
for j=1:length(level2)
    for i=1:length(p)
        a=[p(i),c(i)]';
        if a(1,:)==level2(j)
            level3=[level3, a(2)];
        else
        end
    end
end
```

E.g., you will append result of iteration into the end of current vector.